# app:srcCompat does not work for ImageView

Tags: android, android-support-library, vector-graphics

I'm adding vector drawable support to a library project, and using `app:srcCompat` to reference the vector drawable. The only view that appears to work is ImageButton and I'm not sure why.

Here's the relevant piece of my build.gradle

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
  }
}

dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:24.0.0'
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.2.0'
}
```

Here's my layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iconActive"
        style="@style/Widget.MyCompany.Button.Icon"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/activities"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:tint="@color/white"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

If I simply change the ImageView to an ImageButton it works. Button also does not work.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you could try changing ImageView to [AppCompatImageView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatImageView.html). So it becomes:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
   android:id="@+id/iconActive"
   style="@style/Widget.MyCompany.Button.Icon"
   app:srcCompat="@drawable/activities"
   android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
   android:tint="@color/white"
/>
```

Comment: That doesn't work either. Also, you don't have to explicitly use the AppCompat views, they are created auto-magically for you depending on the version of Android you are running, if you are including the library in your project.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't seem to matter the version of Android.

Comment: @ChristopherPerry If your activity doesn't extend AppCompatActivity then AppCompat views won't "auto-magically" be injected for you. http://stackoverflow.com/a/37561933/196486

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"


<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_cross"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/cross" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Work for me

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"


    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_cross"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/cross" />
```