# ImageView not displaying correctly in the device

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview

I have this layout that I want to use as a header for navigation bar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="164dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/app_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="false"
        android:scaleType="center"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/first_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/app_icon" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/credits_material_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:scaleType="center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_dollar_coin_stack" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/credits_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:text="Credits"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/credits_material_icon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/credits_available"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/credits_label" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

In the layout editor, the layout looks like:

[image]

But on a device, I am getting something like this:

[image]

The encircled portion is the layout under concern. Under that, you can see a `ListView` but that is a child of `LinearLayout` so that is a separate story.

**So, my question is that why none of my `ImageView`s are displaying at all?**

Things I have tried:

- I have tried moving the `ImageView`s around with no improvement.
- I checked with the layout hierarchy with the Layout inspector. Turns out, it shows a literal dot in place of both the `ImageView`s.
- I have tried manually setting the height of this layout to a very large number to solve any accommodation related problems if there are any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simple:

### *When in doubt, use `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView`*

I thought that Android [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatImageView.html) advising **against** its use *in general* was something to be taken seriously.

> This will automatically be used when you use `ImageView` in your
>   layouts. You should only need to manually use this class when writing
>   custom views.

Another place I read that you are supposed to be extending from `AppCompatActivity` to enable this behavior. My Activities DO extend from `AppCompatActivity` but still I spent so much time thinking that maybe something is buggy with `ConstraintLayout` after all.

NO. My *beloved* `ConstraintLayout` hasn't lost its chivalry yet. :)

So, when in doubt, I reiterate,

### **Use `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView`**

---

Some other answers saying the same thing:

[Android vector drawable app:srcCompat not showing images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38221986/android-vector-drawable-appsrccompat-not-showing-images)

[app:srcCompat does not work for ImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38003489/appsrccompat-does-not-work-for-imageview)