# Android vector drawable app:srcCompat not showing images

Tags: android, android-support-library

I'm using support library to show vector images on android kitkat. When I test my app on emulater I don't see any of these images. I made a separate layout for android lollipop and above and it workd perfectly (I think because I'm using `src` attribute instead of `srcCompat`Here's the code where I'm usign support library

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:id="@+id/lake_detail"
android:background="@drawable/my_fishing_plan_footer_line"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="90dp"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:id="@+id/fire_logo"
            android:layout_width="20sp"
            android:layout_height="20sp">

            <ImageView
                android:tint="#d74313"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/circle_icon"
                android:layout_width="30sp"
                android:layout_height="30sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/lauzaviete"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp" />

        </RelativeLayout>
```

and it's strange because I see the images on android studio preview window.

Comment: Use `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView` and make sure you are using the latest support version.

Comment: @Jared Burrows Thank you! Could you write this like an answer? I would like to accept it!

Answer (score 209, accepted):

### Original Answer

Use `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView` instead of `ImageView` in your layout, like this:

```
<LinearLayout 
  ...
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

  <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
    android:tint="#d74313"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/circle_icon"
    android:layout_width="30sp"
    android:layout_height="30sp" />

  <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/lauzaviete"
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

See the `AppCompatImageView` docs [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatImageView.html) and `app:srcCompat` [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatImageView.html#attr_android.support.v7.appcompat:srcCompat).

### Also, make sure to do the following:

**Setup your `build.gradle`**

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
    vectorDrawables {
      useSupportLibrary = true
    }
  }
}
```

Docs: https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.VectorDrawablesOptions.html#com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.VectorDrawablesOptions:useSupportLibrary

**Extend your `Activity` with `AppCompatActivity`**

```
public final class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {    
  @Override protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  }
}
```

**When using `app:srcCompat`, make sure to have the correct declarations in your layout:**

```
<LinearLayout 
  ...
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
  ...
</LinearLayout>
```

**Optional (warning: please read docs): `setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled` in your `Application` class**

```
public class App extends Application {

  @Override public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    // Make sure we use vector drawables
    AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
  }
}
```

**Docs:** https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegate.html#setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(boolean)

Comment: Why doesn't it just work with ImageView in supportLibVersion = '25.0.1'?

Comment: @toobsco42 got any solution for supportLibVersion = '25.0.1'??

Comment: So my issue was that i was not extending AppCompatActivity.  I was extending Activity so i wasn't using the right LayoutInflater and the ImageView was not being replaced with an AppCompatImageView automatically.

Comment: @toobsco42 If you look at the `ImageView` docs, https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html, does not have `srcCompat` but `AppCompatImageView` does: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatImageView.html.

Comment: Why should I use `AppCompatImageView` in layout.

The doc says: "This will automatically be used when you use ImageView in your layouts. You should only need to manually use this class when writing custom views."

Comment: @Ordon Yes you are right. I do know when this was posted, you would get an IDE lint warning when using `ImageView`. I seem to no longer get that anymore.

Comment: That's the most complete answer ever. Thanks so much.

Comment: @JaredBurrows #JustForRecords it is not necessary to extend activity from AppCompatActivity if you use app:srcCompat attribute on android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView

Comment: I was using the SVG along with the react-native-splash-screen and found that ImageView works great when `setContentView` of the SplashActivity, but does not work when `setContentView` of the `PhoneWindow` backing the `Dialog`.  For that reason I had to use `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView` which worked on both Activity and Dialog.

Answer (score 19):

I had a similar issue and after following all steps from [Jared Burrows's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38224549/2615142) the problem was not solved.

Turns out that the "app" namespace inside my layout file was set as:

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

instead of:

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

After changing this the problem was fixed

Comment: Could you tell me the difference between both?

Comment: These schemas are just identifiers for where some features are implemented under the hood by Android, meaning that they don't point to a document like in a URL.
Different schemas are used for various purposes. 
In this case, the srcCompat property was something implemented as part of an initiative to provide certain features to older versions of Android, requiring a different namespace (res-auto) definition than the original.
The "xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" namespace is dedicated to features tied to the IDE, like changing a property only at Android Studio level

Answer (score 15):

Incase anyone else runs into this problem and is using **androidx**, then try using **androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView**

Comment: Why should I use AppCompatImageView in layout. The doc says: "This will automatically be used when you use ImageView in your layouts. You should only need to manually use this class when writing custom views."

Comment: @S.Gissel well, I guess you might be using an updated version. At the time I tried this that was the only solution that worked for my case

Comment: Thank you so much...This fixed my issue. The drawable DOES NOT SHOW when you are inflating the layout in a service and is using ```ImageView```. https://stackoverflow.com/q/68128001/11110509 Need ```AppCompatImageView``` for it to work.

Answer (score 5):

In summary:

1. Put vector drawable support in your module (build.gradle)

   ```
   defaultConfig {           
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
   ```
2. Instead of `android:src="@drawable/icon"` use `app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon"`
3. **Make sure** your `Activity extends AppCompatActivity` without this step is not possible to show vector image with `app:srcCompat`

Comment: This was the case with me. I was extending FragmentActivity. Thank you for adding that explanation!

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
android:background="@drawable/circle_icon"
```

instead of:

```
app:srcCompat="@drawable/circle_icon"
```

Comment: I can consider your answer because it shows the image, so thanks! The bad is that we can't get the feedback when user touch the image.

Comment: In fact it should be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

Implement and `app:srcCompact` and then you can use it on the `ImageView`

`implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'`

Make sure you implement the right version.

Then in your `build.gradle` set `android.defaultConfig.vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true`

```
defaultConfig {

    //...

    vectorDrawables {
        useSupportLibrary true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem  was with my Code as well.
Solution: As Android is upgrading to Androidx Artifacts, 
I used  Instead of Regular  and it Worked!

Answer (score 0):

Additional be sure that your vector drawables located in `drawable` and not in `drawable-anydpi`.

I end up often with problems if the graphics located in `drawable-anydpi` folder.