# Android ImageView does not render in LinearLayout

Tags: android-layout, imageview, drawable

I'm facing a problem which I do not understand. In my activity_main.xml a relative Layout is defined which encapsulates a LinearLayout with ImageViews and a ListView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="de.opti4apps.timely.app.WorkDayListActivity">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/lst_workday_header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="false"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/date" />
        <--...-->
</LinearLayout>


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/ManageWorkTimeList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/lst_workday_header"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" />
```

I have implemented a ListAdapter and set it to my ListView in the WorkDayListActivity.

```
public class WorkDayListActivity extends Activity{

private final List<Day> items = new ArrayList<>();

private DayDataSource dayDataSource = new DayDataSource(this);

private ListView manageWorkTimeList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);



    manageWorkTimeList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ManageWorkTimeList);

    dayDataSource.open();
    items.addAll(dayDataSource.getAllDays());
    dayDataSource.close();


    WorkTimeListAdapter adapter = new WorkTimeListAdapter(this,0,items);
    manageWorkTimeList.setAdapter(adapter);
}
//...
}
```

Now the drawable images which are basically pngs do not render. If I initilise them in the WorkDayListActivity they render on top of each other and not according to the defined position.

[image]

Can anybody explain me why this is the case? Your help is much appreciated!

Thank You!

Comment: Can you post the entire `activity_main` layout?

Comment: I am also going to suggest that you take a look at this SO question: [Android vector drawable app:srcCompat not showing images](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38221986/android-vector-drawable-appsrccompat-not-showing-images) and its accepted answer for some clues about what might be happening.