# My Image doesn't appear on my phone when I run my app

Tags: java, android, xml, image

I've been searching all day for an answer and couldn't find anything, other people were having similar issues and their solutions didn't work for me. I have an ImageView and in the design tab the image shows up perfectly fine. I've tried putting it in several folders, drawable, mipmap (hdpi, mdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, xxxhdpi) all to no avail, the picture is sized properly and I tried using several different scaleTypes, heres the XML in the activity_main

```
    <ImageView
    android:layout_width="322dp"
    android:layout_height="191dp"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/bdaydraw"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="center_vertical|left"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />
```

I tried adding stuff about ImageView in the actual Java code but I always had some minor error I couldn't manage to fix. Any help is extremely appreciated

Comment: have you tried using just `src` in place of `srcCompat`?

Comment: I got Error:(37) No resource identifier found for attribute 'src' in package 'com.(name).(projectname)'

Comment: I meant `android:src` attribute. Maybe you just changed the `srcCompat` and made it `app:src`

Answer (score 1):

Ya You can try to use src instead of srcCompat but also can you post the parent layout? Check you did not mess up the match_parent-fill_parent stuff

Answer (score 0):

Use `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView`
instead of `ImageView`.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38221986/android-vector-drawable-appsrccompat-not-showing-images) answer for more