# Vector drawable not showing in app icon below 5.0 api level

Tags: android

I am using vector drawable for my app, and in the app, vector drawables are properly working for 4.2.1 or grater. but only the app icon is not showing for api level 4.4.4 or below.

this is file name, app_logo.xml . i.e. in drawable folder.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android vector drawable app:srcCompat not showing images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38221986/android-vector-drawable-appsrccompat-not-showing-images)

Comment: @OussemaAroua, that issue is different, i did all changes so my app is working fine if i use drawable in app. But my issue is that, the application App icon on android dashboard is not showing my app icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding your icon as an "Image Asset," so that all the different DPI (dots per inch) versions of the icon are created.

This will make sure that your icon is handled even at lower resolution versions.

Comment: so you mean, we can't use vector drawable for app icon below 5.0 ?

Comment: Yes! You need to use a image asset instead. I've faced this exact problem before and this is how I solved it.

Comment: Thanks Joey, its working. But the quality is very poor.

Comment: Just want to know, how we can set a good quality icon with bigger resolution from api level 17 to latest?