# ImageButton not visible on Android Studio on Emulator or physical device

Tags: android, calculator

Hello the great community. I am new to Android and trying to build a calculator and this is the first time I am having this problem, not sure what is wrong. I have added `buttons` and they look fine on emulator except `image button`. The code is below, I was hoping to get help.

[image]

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:weightSum="4">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button16"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:text="7"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
            android:textSize="30sp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:text="8"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
            android:textSize="30sp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:text="9"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
            android:textSize="30sp"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/divide"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

The last button divide is not visible and I have added four such linear layouts with 1, 2, 3, minus, 4, 5, 6, multiply buttons, all these multiply, divide, plus and minus `buttons` aren't visible unfortunately.
I am just starting out and was hoping to know where am I wrong and what is that I need to fix.

**UPDATE**

[image]

See the above image I have attached. In this visible `Views` in the emulator are `Buttons` if I change them to `ImageButton` the `views` like the equal sign. I have change my `png's` file but I can't get what I am doing wrong

Thank you

Comment: this code is working at my side may be the problem is in your svg image

Comment: I guess you are right, I changed these to plain buttons and it has worked all fine, image buttons are also working when background is changed, looking for other images to see if it fixes, thanks

Comment: what are you using svg or png file for images @Pankaj

Comment: they are png. I just created new png myself and tried to add image button again but it is still not visible on the emulator or physical device when it is showing up on the screen. What could be the cause?

Comment: try `android:src="@drawable/divide"/>` at the place of `app:srcCompat="@drawable/divide"/>`

Comment: It screwed the image up even further, image gone and grey background appears on a shrunken place. I have attached the screenshot. In blueprint, all those with white border are showing up but all other imageButtons with grey border aren't. I changed the image and still not worked. I even tried with imageview instead of imagebutton, still not worked.

Comment: can you post a screen shot here

Comment: and try icons from [here](https://www.flaticon.com/search?word=add)

Comment: I am not sure how to post screenshot here. Attaching above with question.

Comment: Visible symbols arent imageButtons but normal buttons. equal symbol is only imagebutton which is not visible. Not sure why. Please see

Comment: is your problem solved

Comment: No Vikas, I tried imagebutton on two more projects, different than calculator, on one, it worked, on another, it didn't. I am going crazy now :(

Comment: Can you upload your code on github then I will able to examine... what's going wrong...may be possible then I will help you better

Comment: here you go Vikas - 
https://github.com/therisingsun39/CalceeApp

The imageButtons need to be there instead of buttons for add multiply divide etc

Comment: now see my answer below :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved this issue and this is working now, as I have changed only one line to your every `ImageButton` is `android:src="@drawable/equalsymbol"` instead of `app:srcCompat="@drawable/equalsymbol"` which I have already mention to you in comment section

See the Screen Shot attached below-:

[image]

**EDIT**

**Now, The Question is why `app.srcCompat` not working**

This because you have **`extend`** your **`MainAcyivity.java`** with **`Activity`**

You have to **`Extend`** with **`AppCompatActivity`**

**and** need to update your `gradle.build`

You have to add following lines -:

```
vectorDrawables {
      useSupportLibrary = true
    }
```

see the detailed answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38221986/android-vector-drawable-appsrccompat-not-showing-images)

Then, I make again some changes to your app

**Change 1**

**`MainActivity.java`**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  }
}
```

**Change 2**

**`style.xml`**

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <!--<item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>-->
    <!--<item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>-->
    <!--<item name="android:colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>-->
</style>
```

**Change 3**

**`build.gradle`**

```
 android {
  defaultConfig {
    vectorDrawables {
      useSupportLibrary = true
    }
  }
}
```

Now, you can use `app:srcCompat="@drawable/equalsymbol"` in your app

See, Second screenshot below I have used `app:srcCompat` and now this is working

[image]

Now, Everything is working fine.

So, make changes as mentioned above. Happy Coding

Comment: You simply are genius Vikas, it did work, I was going mad to see all the answers weren't working and searching on internet was in vain, you are angel, thank you again.

Comment: I am not genius nor angel...man...glad it works for you... Happy Coding

Comment: Thank you again Vikas, you are awesome and kind!

Comment: Hahahaha...Welcome @PankajDhawan By the way I am also from Delhi.

Comment: Buddy, I am facing challenges but I am interested in learning this Android thing. I wasn't sure where to begin with since YouTube was too fast for me and I couldn't understand them. Bought course on Udemy since my job can't allow me to study due to time constraint but I really want to be more fluent. Any tips or suggestions?
Plus I really would love to meet you in person to thank you, people like you deserve a treat for sure as thanks is not enough :)

Comment: we cant talk here. So, [here](http://ultimatedevil17.blogspot.in/) is my blog you can get my email from here. lets talk on hangout.

Answer (score 0):

Use width(or height for vertical LinearLayout) of 0dp if you are using weight.

```
android:layout_width = "0dp"
android:layout_height ="80dp"
android:layout_weight ="1"
```

Comment: Thanks Nabin but this hasn't worked. It moved the button further to left but didn't show the imagebuttons.

Comment: Did you do that for all 4 buttons in the row?

Comment: yes Nabin, I just retried as you suggested. In the blueprint in activity_main, I see all the buttons bordered white and they are visible but these imagebuttons are bordered gray and they are all invisible. I have also attached image of how it is looking on emulator and on studio.

Comment: You have used `android:background ="#00000000"` in your ImageButton, which means transparent background. Try different color to see what's happening. Also your image may be small. Use scaleType fitCenter in your ImageButton

Comment: As you suggested, I changed the hex code for background to #006699 and it got blue box, at least showed something but not the divide symbol. Do you think there is problem with drawable image or something to do with it

Comment: The problem is surely with the image. Did you try the fitCenter scaleType?

Comment: Hey Nabin, I tried that too and tried new image as well. Just any imagebutton anywhere on the main activity is not working on emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Did you declare the botton in your Java class, also your Drawable has the file in png it's the  best way to work with img files.

Comment: I haven't got into java class yet, my imagebuttons are not visible in layout on physical device or emulator. Do you think declaring in MainActivity.java might help?